# fminsearch usage with likelihood

Tags: math, matlab

I wrote the code below for a given data. I probably do a mistake by writing nested functions. Could anyone show me the error? I'll be happy for any kind answer,

```
    clear;
    t=[1 3 6 9 12 18]';%time
    y=[.94 .77 .40 .26 .24 .16]';%probability
    n=100;%trial
    x=y.*n;%correct replies
    p=rand(2,1);%starting parameters
    f=@(t)p(1,1).*t.^(-p(2,1));%model function
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    ff=@(p)sum(x.*log(-f)+(n-x(i).*log(-1+f)));%sum of the -loglikelihood
    ffmin1=fminsearch(ff,p(1,1))
    ffmin2=fminsearch(ff,p(2,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors in the code. Going line by line:

Your model function should accept your parameters

```
f=@(t,p) p(1,1).*t.^(-p(2,1));%model function
```

Your objective function cannot call `f` without parameters, and cannot index `x` by `i`, which is not defined.

```
ff= @(p) sum(x.*log(-f(t,p))+((n-x).*log(-1+f(t,p))));
```

`fminsearch` will solve the minimization problem with all variables simultaneously, not one at a time.

```
ffmin=fminsearch(ff,p)
```

This does not account for possible errors in your model, but at least the code should run.

Comment: I thank you very much for your answer, @jonnat.I've tried to let the code run, but I unfortunately recieve an error message. Do you have any idea on it?

Comment: Many thanks, I got my mistake fminsearch is a matrixvalue and I should have written something like:{[p fvalue]=fminsearch(ff,p)
}

Comment: @user1018331 The maxiter warning indicates that `fminsearch` is having trouble converging to a minimum within the allowed number of iterations, possibly due to the problem being unbounded. I have made small alterations in the code in my response which yielded a bounded problem, but I have no way to know if the model is correct.